# Parsing through .txt file

Tags: c#

I am reading a txt file. Then I try to parse that for each element to start a new row so I can later iterate through the file.

```
class ReadFromFile
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\filip\Desktop\String.txt");
        for ( int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] rowData = lines[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 0; j < rowData.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rowData[j]);
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried this but still its not splitting the string in new row. The txt files contains

> {()()()((((()))))()()()()()(}

there are maybe 1000+ elements in the txt file.

How can I properly parse so on every `(` or ')' I get a new row ?

Txt file data:

```
(((())))()((((((((())()(()))(()((((()(()(((()((()((()(()()()()()))(((()(()((((((((((())(()()((())()(((())))()(()(()((()(()))(()()()()((()((()(((()()(((((((()()())()((((()()(((((()(())()(())((())()()))()(((((((())(()())(()(((())(()))((())))(()((()())))()())((((())))(()(((((()(())(((()()((()((()((((((((((())(()())))))()))())()()((((()()()()()()((((((())())(((()())()((()()(((()()()))(((((()))(((()(()()()(()(()(((())()))(()(((()((())()(()())())))((()()()(()()(((()))(((()((((()(((((()()(()())((()())())(()((((((()(()()))((((()))))())((())()()((()(()))))((((((((()))(()()(((())())(())()((()()()()((()((()((()()(((())))(()((())()((((((((()((()(()()(((())())())))(())())))()((((()))))))())))()()))()())((()())()((()()()))(()()(((()(())((((())())((((((((()()()()())))()()()((((()()))))))()((((()(((()))(()()())))((()()(((()))()()())())(((())((()()(())()()()(((())))))()())((()))()))((())()()())()())()()(()))())))())()))(())((()(())))(()(())(()))))(()(())())(()(())(()(()))))((()())()))()((((()()))))())))()()())((())()((()()()))()(((()(()))))(())()()))(((()())))))))))(((())))()))())()))))()()(((())))))))()(()()(()))((()))))((())))((()((())))())))()()(()))())()(()((()())(()(()()())())(()()))()))))(()())()()))()()()()))(()(()(()))))))()(()))()))()()(()((())(()(())))()(((())(())())))))()(()(()))))()))(()()()(())()(()(())))()))))()()(((((())))))())()())())())()())()))))()))))))))())()()()()()()())))()))((())()))())))()((())()))))()))())))))))())()()()))()()(()((((()(((((((()(())((()())((()()))()))))(())))()()()(())((())()())))(())))(())))(((()()))()(())(((()(()))((())))())()))((((()))())()))))))))()(())())))(()))()(()()))())()()(())())))())()()(()())))()((()())(()(())(())))))))))))))(()))))()))))))()()())(()(((((()(()())))())()))(()))()))(()()))()())(()))())()(())((()()))))))())))())()(((())))(()(()))()()))()(()))))))((()())(()))))))()())))()()))))))))((((((((()()()(()))))))()())))())))()()((())()))((())(())))())())))()()()((()((()(())))())()(())))))))))()())))()()()()()()))()))((())())(()(()))))))(()()))()))(())))()))))))))))))(()))))))))()))))()))()())()))()()))))))()))))((()))))(()))())()(())))(()())((((()())))()))))(()))()(()()(())))))())))))()))))))())))())))))())))())())))())(()))))(())()(())))())()))((()()))))))())))((())))))))())))(())))))()()())))))())))))()))))))()))()()()(()(((()())())())(()))())))))((()(())(()))))))))(())))()()()())())(()))))()()()))()))())())())()(())))()(((()((((())))))))()))))))))))))))))))))((())()())(()))))()()))))))(()()(())())))())))((())))((())))))))))))))()))))()(()))))))())))))()))(()()())(()())))))))))()))))))(())))))()()))()())(((())))()))(()))))))))(())())))())))())())())()()))((())()(())()())()))()())(())(()))))()())))(()(((()))))))()(()())()()()))()))))))))()()()(())()())()(((((()))()())())(()))))()()()(())))())))()((()())))(()))())()(()())())(()))()()))((()()))((()()()()())))(())()))(()(())))((()()))))))))())))))))())()()))))))))))))))))(())()(())(())()())())()))()(()))))())())))))()())()(()))()()(())))(())())))))(()))))))))))))))())())(())(())))(((()))()))))())((())(()))())))))))())))))())))()))()))))))))))))())()))))()))))((()))(())))()(())))(())()))()))())))())))))))()(()())())))()()())))(())))))(()))))))))))))(()))()))()))())))(((()()()(())((()())))()())(((()))(())()))((()()()())))())(())(()))))()(((((())))(()))())())))))))((((()()()))())())()(()(()())))))))))()())())))(())))()())(((()(())())()()))())())))))))((()())((()()(()))(()(())))()))()))(()))(()))()()(()(((())((((()))()(()))((())()(()(()())()(()))()())))))(()))()))())()())))())))(())))((())(()())))))()))(())(()))()())()(()()((()(()))))))()(())(()())(())()))(((())()))(()()(()()()))))(()(())))()))))())))))())(()()()()()()(((())))(()()))()((())(((((()()())))(()))(()))()()))(((())())()(((()()()()))))(()))(())())))()())(()()())())))))))()))))((())))()())(()))(()(()))())))))())(())))))()()())())()))()()(())))(()))(())((((((())(()))(()))())()))(()()(())))()))(()()))()))()(())))(())))((()(()))(())()()())())))(((()()())(())()))))))()(((()(((((()()(((())(())))())()((()))))((()())()(())(((())))(((()((()(()(()))(()()))())(()))(())(())))()))))))((((()))()((((()(()))()))()()))))()(()(()))()(()((()(((()(()()(((()))))()(((()(()(()(((()(()())())()()(()(()())())(()((((())(()))()))(((((()()())(())()((()()())))()()(((()()))()((((((((()(())))())((()))))(())))(()))))((()((((()()(())(((((()))(((((((((((((()())))((((()(((()((())())()))((()))()(()()((()()()()(()()(()(()(((())()(()((((((()((()()((())()((((()((()()(()()())((()()()((()((())()(()(((()((())((((())(()))((()(()))(()())()((((((((()(((((((((((()))(()(((()(()()()((((())((())()())()))(())((())(()))(((()((()(())))(()))))((()()))))((((()(()(()())(()(())((((((((()((((()((()(((((()))())()(()))(()()((()(())(((((()(())()(((((()()))))))()(((())()(()()((((())()((())((()(((())(((()))((()()((((()(())))))((()((((()((()((()(((())((()))(((((((()(((()((((((((())()))((((())(((((()((((((((()(((()((()(((()()(((()((((((()()(()((((((((()()(()(()(())((((()())()))))(((()))((((())((((()())((()(())()((()((((((()((((((()(())))()())(((())())())()(())()(()())((()()((((())((((((())(()(((((()((((())()((((()(()(())(()())(((())()((())((((()))()((((((())(()(((()(((()((((((()(((()))(()()())())((()((()())()((((())(((()(()(((((((((())(())))()((()()()()(())((()))(((((((()(((((((((()(()))))(()((((((((()((((()((()()((((((()()(((((((()(()(())()(())((()()()((()(((((()())()(((((()())()()((()(()())(()()()(((()()(((((()((((((()()((()(()()()((((((((((((()((((((((()()(((()())))()(((()()(())())((((()((((()((((()()()(())(())((()(()(((((((((((((((()(())(())))))()()))((()(((()(())((()(((()(()()((((()()(((()(((()(((((()()((()(()(((()))((((((()((((((((()((()((())(((((()(((())(())())((()()))((((())()()((()(((()(((((()()(((()))(((()(()(((((((((((((()))((((((((()(((()))))())((((((((((((())((())((()())(((())((())(()((((((((((()(((())((()()(()((())(((((((((((()))((((((((((((()(()())((()((()((()(()(((()((((((((()()(()((()(()(((()))((()))(((((((((((((()(())((((((())(((()(())(()(()(()((()()))((((()((((()((((())))())((((()((((()))((((((()((((((()((()(((())))((())(()))(()((()((((()((()(((()()))((((()()()(((((((())(((())(()))())((((()())(((()(((((((((((()(()(()((()(((((((((((((((()()((((()((((((((()(((()()((()((((()))(((()(())((((((()((((())()((((()((()))(())()(()(((()((())())((((((()(()(())())(((())(()(()())(((((()((()((())()())(())))(((()(())))))))(((()(((()))()((()(((()()((()())()()))())))(((()))(()(((()(((((((((()(()(((((()()(((()())()()))))()(((()))(((()(()(()(()(()))()(())()))(()(((())))(()))))))))))(())((()((())((()(())()(())((()()((((()()((()()))((())(((()((()(())(())))()(()(((((()((()))())()(((((()()(((()(()((((((())(()))(())()))((()(()()))(())())()))(((())))(()((()(((())(())())))((()()((((((((((((((()((()(()()(()(((()))())()()((()()()(())(()))(()())(((())((())()(())()()(()()(())))((()(((()))))(((()()(()()))())((()((())()))((((()()()())((())))(((()(())(((((()(((((()((()(()((((()()(((()()()(((()())(((()()((((())(()))(((()))(())())((()))(((()((()))(((()()((())((()(((((()((((()()())((()))()((((()((()(()()()(
```

Comment: Please give an example of the lines in the file, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I want the data to be split in this way so each ( or ) to be written in a new line

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to achieve but lines[i].Split(','): here you are spliting the line based on comma character ','. There are no ',' in example you provided.

Comment: I would suggest to use a simple for-loop approach and a stringbuilder

Comment: I am trying to have every ( or ) be wrote in a new row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this and tell me if this is what you needed.

```
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\filip\Desktop\String.txt"))
{
    foreach(var c in line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a simple for-loop approach and a stringbuilder:

```
string line = "()()((()))()(";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

List<char> delimiters = new List<char>{'(', ')'};

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    if (delimiters.Contains(line[i]))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line[i].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(line[i]);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output:

> (
> )
> (
> )
> (
> (
> (
> )
> )
> )
> (
> )
> (